# FutureBuilder not updating ItemCount after filtering

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I have my Apply button which applies the values selected in the RangeSlider. The list gets updated correctly while debugging.

```
ElevatedButton(
                            child: const Text('Apply'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                isFiltering = true;

                                if (varSelectedFilterAgeStart == null) {
                                  varSelectedFilterAgeStart = 0.0;

                                  // ignore: prefer_conditional_assignment
                                } else if (varSelectedFilterAgeEnd == null) {
                                  varSelectedFilterAgeEnd = 20.0;
                                }
                                snapList = snapListAll;

                                _filteredDogList = snapList.where((element) {
                                  return element['Age'] >=
                                          varSelectedFilterAgeStart &&
                                      element['Age'] <= varSelectedFilterAgeEnd;
                                }).toList();
                              });
                              Navigator.of(context).pop(_rangeValues);
                            },
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: const Text('Cancel'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          ),
```

HOwever, I have to Hot Reload to actually see the results updated in the UI. Meanwhile, I am only getting the error (for every item):

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 4

I build my GridView with FutureBuilder like this:

```
  key: _scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: FutureBuilder<List<ParseObject>>(
            future: futuregetalldogs,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    // child: getwid.GFShimmer(
                    //child: emptyBlock,
                  );
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return const Center(
                      child: Text("Error..."),
                    );
                  }
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Center(
                      child: Text("No Data..."),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return GridView.builder(
                      key:  UniqueKey(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                      itemCount: _filteredDogList!.isEmpty
                          ? snapshot.data!.length
                          : snapList.length, // snapshot.data!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        snapListAll = snapshot.data;

                        //*************************************
                        if (_filteredDogList!.isEmpty) {
                          snapList = snapshot.data;
                        } else {
                          snapList = _filteredDogList!;
                        }
                        //*************************************     
                        final varTodo        = snapList[index];
                        final varTitle       = varTodo.get<String>('title')!;
                        final varBreed       = varTodo.get<String>('Breed');
                        final varAge         = varTodo.get<int>('Age');
                        final varImg         = varTodo.get<ParseFileBase>('DogImg')!;
                        final varDogDesc     = varTodo.get<String>('DogDescription')!;
                        final varGender      = varTodo.get<String>('Gender')!;
                        final varCity        = varTodo.get<String>('CityName')!;
                        final varCountryName = varTodo.get<String>('CountryName')!;
                        final varlat         = varTodo.get<double>('latitude');
                        final varlong        = varTodo.get<double>('longitude');

                        //*************************************
                        //this is only to show a dialog with several options. Not relevant for the question.
                        return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (context) {
                                    return
                                  
                                        LongPressGridCard(
                                            index: index,
                                            Age: varAge,
                                            title: varTitle,
                                            img: varImg,
                                            breed: varBreed,
                                            description: varDogDesc,
                                            lat: varlat,
                                            long: varlong);
                                  });
                            },
                            //this is the part that shows the cards.
                            child: GridAllCards(
                                
                                key: UniqueKey(),
                                index: index,
                                image: varImg.url,
                                title: varTitle,
                                gender: varGender,
                                city: varCity,
                                country: varCountryName));
                      },
                      gridDelegate:
                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                        mainAxisExtent: 264,
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              }
            }));
```

My question is: how can I refresh correctly the UI? I am getting the values inside my list `_filteredDogList` properly, but UI does not react instantly to changes.

This is what I am getting visually:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your RangeError problem happens because you have some logic on your GridView.builder to check _filteredDogList!.isEmpty, but in your itemBuilder you only use snapshot.data to fill snapList...

i mean, what if _filteredDogList have 5 items, but your snapshot.data have 3 items, in this case your GridView will indexing 5 items but consume data that only have 3 items

I'm not sure maybe try do this to set your snapList data

```
if(filteredDogList!.isEmpty){
   snapList = snapshot.data;
}else{
   snapList = filteredDogList;
}

... the rest of your code ...

///Remove the return logic
return GridAllCards(
   image: varImg.url,
   title: varTitle,
   gender: varGender,
   city: varCity,
   country: varCountryName
)


///I'm not sure what does 'child:' mean in your code, i think it must be like return
```

Comment: Hi, I think it was a good idea to include the conditional you have said. I included it just to keep it more organized, but it does not solve my problem though. I am still with the same problem and I am only able to update my UI through Hot reload